# getting empty dataframes from dcc.store object

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am building my first dash dashboard.

I have a function that returns 3 dataframes. When executing the function, all 3 dataframes contain values. In the first callback, I am storing the dataframes in 3 different objects dcc.store() as json files.

I am supposed then to print the first dcc.store object 'to_show_dataframe' and to plot the second one 'to_show_dataframe'.

Here is all the code I am using:

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    ## element div 1
    html.Div(children=[dcc.Store(id='main_data'), dcc.Store(id='to_plot_data'), dcc.Store(id='to_show_dataframe'),
    dcc.Textarea(id='portfolio_id-example', value='940', style={'width': 70, 'height': 30},),
    html.Button('get data', id='submit-button', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='textarea-state-example-output', style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-line'})
                      ]),
    ## element div 2 for statistics table
    html.Div(children=[
        html.H4(children='lengths of all original data'),
        html.Table(id='data_to_show')
                      ]),
    ## element div 3 for length plots
    html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='all_lengths_graph'))
    
])

@app.callback(
    Output('main_data', 'data'),
    Output('to_plot_data', 'data'),
    Output('to_show_dataframe', 'data'),
    Input('portfolio_id-example', 'value'),
    Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks'),)
def update_output(n_clicks, value):
    if (int(n_clicks) > 0):
        df, to_plot_in_dataframe, descriptive_statistics_table_before=first_preprocessing(int(value))
        return df.to_json(orient='split'), to_plot_in_dataframe.to_json(orient='split'), descriptive_statistics_table_before.to_json(orient='split')
    else:
        return print('error in clicks')
    

@app.callback(Output('data_to_show', 'children'),
              Input('to_show_dataframe', 'data'),)
def for_table(data):
    a=pd.read_json(data, orient='split')
    return a


@app.callback(Output('all_lengths_graph', 'figure'),
              Input('to_plot_data', 'data'),)
def for_plot(data):
    table=pd.read_json(data, orient='split')
    a = px.scatter(x=range(table.shape[0]), y=table['original_lengths_values'])
    return a
```

There are the only errors I am getting that show empty dataframes

[image]

[image]

Note: I don't know what 'children' means, just a copy paste from internet.